# c# Create list of selected time intervals

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I'm trying to create a downtown that will display times from 00:00 to 24:59 at a selected number of intervals (and this could change from 5 minutes to 10 minutes etc

so for example a list of

```
00:10
00:20
00:30
```

or could be

```
00:15 
00:30
```

I'm using the following which works, but only for a selected number of iterations (33):

```
List<string> query = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 33)
  .Select(i => DateTime.Today
     .AddHours(0)
     .AddMinutes(i * (double)IntervalParameter)
     .ToString())
  .ToList();
```

*IntervalParameter = 10 for the example above.

I'm looking to adapt this so it runs the full 24 hours time frame. Just looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Not `Enumerable.Range(0, (1440 / IntervalParameter))`?

Comment: Define "most efficient" - You could just have a ready-to-use lists for each interval ranging from 1 minute to 1440 (24 hours * 60 minutes) and pick the correct one. It's going to be the fastest but will use the most memory. Since we are talking about populating a dropdown, I'm sure it doesn't happen 10000 times per second so the "most efficient" requirement is kinda redundant. I mean, you could probably find a way to do it in less than 100 ms that is still readable, and a way to do it in less than 10 ms that is complicated to understand and debug... Go with clarity first, performance later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not compute the *number of items*?

```
int IntervalParameter = 5;

// .Range(0, 1440 / IntervalParameter) - see Zohar Peled's comment -  
// is brief, but less readable
List<string> query = Enumerable
  .Range(0, (int) (new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0).TotalMinutes / IntervalParameter))
  .Select(i => DateTime.Today
     .AddMinutes(i * (double)IntervalParameter) // AddHours is redundant
     .ToString("HH:mm"))                        // Let's provide HH:mm format 
  .ToList();
```

Comment: `new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0).TotalMinutes` might as well be written as hard coded 1440 (though I understand the reasoning for writing it the way you did). Good answer.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: yes, you are quite right: 1 day = 24 hours = **1440** *minutes* = 86400 seconds, but let me avoid magic values: the question itself is about range calculation and my goal is to show what is the upper value and why

Comment: @the_tr00per please accept this answer if it helped you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> Intervals(TimeSpan inclusiveStart, TimeSpan exclusiveEnd, TimeSpan increment)
{
    for (var time = inclusiveStart; time < exclusiveEnd; time += increment)
        yield return time;
}
```

Example usage:

```
foreach (var time in Intervals(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromDays(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(time);
}
```